# twitter bootstrap "multiselect dropdown checkbox" not getting selected in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9

I am having a table which has 1st cell as "bootstrap multiselect dropdown checkbox" and 2nd cell as normal dropdown select option. Everything works fine in IE11 and chrome but same thing if i test in IE9 , i am not able to select any option in "bootstrap multiselect dropdown checkbox" . In console it shows `SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'prop': object is null or undefined` . To fix that i tried  `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8;FF=3;OtherUA=4" />` .Now i am able to select check box in multiselect drop down . But Now for 2nd cell , normal dropdown select option `cells[1].children[0].value` always gives null.

```
In short if I fix "bootstrap multiselect dropdown checbox" issue , i am not able to get values from 2nd cell normal dropdown select option." 
Hope my problem is clear .
```

Here is jsfiddle link :-
http://jsfiddle.net/77c2g3sg/1/

Comment: If you can put it into a JSFiddle I will have a look for you.

Comment: @MatthewNorth :sure , thanks for helping me out..i will create jsfiddle link

Comment: @MatthewNorth :- here it is http://jsfiddle.net/77c2g3sg/1/

Comment: I've just tried it (ie-11 with document mode set to ie-9) and it seems to be working okay, I did have to change the JQuery version to 1.11.0 (there are issues with some versions of JQuery and the IFrame in JSFiddle). Do you get any other errors in the console?

Comment: @MatthewNorth : Thanks for your help :) ..and sorry for late reply..i decided to switch to jquery-multiselect dropdown instead of bootstrap..